# не получается сделать парсер на python

Tags: python, telegram, beautiful-soup, aiogram

не получается запарсить раздел новостей, нужно чтобы парсились картинка,заголовок и ссылка, и дальее отправлялись через бота пользователю, написал код и не могу понять в чем проблема, уже 2 день сижу пытаясь сделать парсер

```
async def parser(message: types.message):
url = "https://aues.edu.kz/ru/site/admissions/"
print(url)
request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

all_links = soup.find_all("div", class_="addmission_news")
print(len(all_links))
for link in all_links:
    url = "https://aues.edu.kz/ru/site/admissions/" + link["href"]
    request = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

    name = soup.find("div", class_="addmission_news")
    price = name.find("a").text
    name.find("a").extract()
    name = name.text

    img = soup.find("div", class_="addmission_news")
    img = img.findChildren("img")[0]
    img = "https://aues.edu.kz/ru/site/admissions/" + img["src"]

    await message.answer_photo(message.chat.id, img,
                         caption="<b>" + name + "</b>\n<i>" + price + f"</i>\n<a href='{url}'>Ссылка на сайт</a>",
                         parse_mode="html")

    if all_links.index(link) == 9:
        break

if len(all_links) == 0:
    await message.answer(message.chat.id, "Ничего не найдено")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "https://aues.edu.kz/ru/site/admissions/"
request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

all_links = soup.find_all("div", class_="addmission_news_part")
for link in all_links:
    url = "https://aues.edu.kz/ru" + link.a["href"]
    request = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

    nam = soup.find('div', class_="container col-md-10 ever_news")
    img = "https://aues.edu.kz" + nam.img['src']
    title = nam.img['alt']
    print(title)
    print(img)
    print(url)
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое!! работает!!